# Update maxclients setting in apache configuration file of AWS elastic bean stalk instance

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have updated  **/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf** file of elastic beanstalk instance with this.

```
<IfModule prefork.c>
StartServers       8
MinSpareServers    5
MaxSpareServers   20
ServerLimit     1000
MaxClients      1000
MaxRequestsPerChild  4000
</IfModule>
```

After that i restarted my httpd service using

```
sudo service httpd restart
```

Now if i have 300 clients running at a time, then apache is still throwing this error.

```
[error] server reached MaxClients setting, consider raising the MaxClients setting.
```

What should i do to update maxclients setting effectively?

Answer (score 0):

Try [this](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/misc/perf-tuning.html) or [this](http://techmythsworld.blogspot.in/2011/11/solving-httpd-maxclients-and-modstatus.html) or [this](http://rainbow.chard.org/2014/12/22/are-you-hitting-maxclients-without-even-knowing-it/). I have not yet tried this practically . you can try it out .